# Subsetting based on combinations from an inner query

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm using `postgres` on `Redshift`. I have a query which goes like this:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(year from created_at) AS CustomYear,
             client_ip,
             member_id,
             COUNT(*) AS Views
      FROM ads.fbs_page_view_staging
      WHERE member_id = 2
      GROUP BY CustomYear,
               client_ip,
               member_id
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
      ORDER BY CustomYear
```

Here, I'm selecting a combination of `client_ip` and `member_id` where `Views` is 1. I would now like to take these combinations of `client_ip` and `member_id` and subset the entire table `ads.fbs_page_view_staging` having only such combinations.

If there was only one column I wanted to subset on, say `client_ip`, I could've written the following query and got the results:

```
    SELECT EXTRACT(year FROM created_at) AS CustomYear,
       COUNT(*)
FROM ads.fbs_page_view_staging
WHERE member_id = 2
AND   client_ip IN (SELECT client_ip
                    FROM ((SELECT EXTRACT(year from created_at) AS CustomYear,
                                  client_ip,
                                  member_id,
                                  COUNT(*)
                           FROM ads.fbs_page_view_staging
                           WHERE member_id = 2
                           GROUP BY CustomYear,
                                    client_ip,
                                    member_id
                           HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                           ORDER BY CustomYear)))
GROUP BY customyear
ORDER BY customyear
```

Notice that in the outer query, I am subsetting based on `client_ip`. But how do I subset the table on a combination of columns?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it might help if you would describe exactly what rows you want to see in your final results. I understand you want a subset based on the subquery, but could you describe it more precisely?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subquerying, try joining directly to the results of your query. That way you can specify multiple criteria.

Here is (draft) SQL to select IP/member pairs that match the rows found by your sub-query (i.e. for some year in the past, there was only one view for that IP & member.)

```
SELECT distinct client_ip, member_id
FROM ads.fbs_page_view_staging Staging
INNER JOIN (SELECT EXTRACT(year from created_at) AS CustomYear,
         client_ip,
         member_id,
         COUNT(*) AS Views
  FROM ads.fbs_page_view_staging
  WHERE member_id = 2
  GROUP BY CustomYear,
           client_ip,
           member_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) SingularViews
ON SingularViews.client_ip=Staging.client_ip 
AND SingularViews.member_id=Staging.member_id
ORDER BY Staging.client_ip, Staging.member_id
```

I'm not certain I've captured the intent of your query correctly, but if not hopefully you can adapt the technique.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I did not get the results I was hoping for. When I aggregate (count) the results each year, I get a set of results which is different from what I get after aggregating (count) the results each year after I join the results from the inner subquery.